# Last grand tour won on aluminum?

Tags: road-bike, racing, aluminum

What was the last grand tour won on an aluminum frame?  Also, any details about the bike itself and the rider would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't give you a definite answer, but I might be able to help you along the way. I know that the last non-carbon winner of the Tour de France was Pantani, in 1998, on an alu frame. I know he also won the Giro that year. What I'm not sure about, is whether the Giro or Vuelta were won, post-1998, on aluminium. If this is the case, there's only really a couple of years window, as carbon was pretty much ubiquitous by the early 2000s

Comment: But keep in mind that last aluminium   victory is not followed by first carbon victory. Carbon was there by 1986 it seems, and LeMond rode carbon and kevlar mix on that tour he won. And there were also mixed carbon - aluminium frames. Ther is more info in http://www.lookcycle.com/en/it/look-cycle/histoire.html

Comment: Jan Ullrich (Team Telecom) won the 1999 Vuelta on a Pinarello which I _believe_ was aluminium. See [www.pinarello.com/en/hall-of-fame/2000-jan-ullrich](http://www.pinarello.com/en/hall-of-fame/2000-jan-ullrich)

Comment: @PeteH - That page is ambiguous - it talks about the '99 Vuelta, but it says "2000" at the top. And here's a picture of Ullrich in '99, that's definitely not the same bike: http://photos.grahamwatson.com/Print-Gallery/JanJan/i-Qb8DZbn

Comment: @MikeBaranczak yeah, my interpretation of the page is that he rode that alu bike (or variations on it) up until 2000, and in 2000 he won the World TT and the Olympics, but not any grands tours. But I agree, it's not explicit.

Answer (score 6):

Abraham Olano won the 1998 Vuelta on an alloy frame. That might be the last Grand Tour win on alloy - as the Vuelta is the last Grand Tour of the year.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the source of this information? Do you have any more info about the frame itself?

Comment: Hope this helps http://rodafixa.blogspot.com/2012/04/pinarello-paris-banesto-1998-de-abraham.html

Answer (score 5):

[According to this article,](http://gizmodo.com/100-years-of-tour-de-france-bikes-map-the-evolution-of-709973821) the last Tour De France win on an aluminum frame (a Bianchi ridden by Marco Pantani) was 1998.

It also says that the last TDF win on a steel bike was 1994. It's interesting that aluminum had such a brief run.

Comment: Nice find. Is gizmodo the only source for this?

Comment: I couldn't find any other sources, but I spent a few minutes with Google, and couldn't find any counter-examples post-1998.

Comment: There's plenty of evidence supporting the first paragraph, I googled "bike history tour de france" and got several interesting articles, in particular [this one](http://www.bikeradar.com/road/gear/article/tour-de-france-winning-bikes-34375/). Also, some of us poor souls are old enough to just remember this stuff. Interesting if you look at TdF 1997, won by Ullrich on an alu Pinarello. Ullrich also won the Vuelta in 1999, I wonder what bike he was riding?

Comment: I would suggest vibration and small bump compliance would be the reason for the short run for aluminum.